# php, how to require something which is not in file?

Tags: php, caching, require

I want to require/include a content from database record, but require/include only accepts files. This thing is related to caching, so I dont want to write anything to file (collisions etc). How to dodge it?

Comment: Please clarify what sort of "content" you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since others have covered `eval()` and the fact that this is a bad idea, I will touch on the topic of writing this "content" to a file.  Use [`tempnam`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php).  This will give you the name of a just-created unique filename with 0600 permissions.  You can then open it, write your content, close, then require/include.  See Example #1 on the [`tempnam`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) man page.

Make sure to check that the return value of `tempnam` is not false; make sure to `unlink` the file after you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Are you fetching PHP code from a database? If so, you're probably doing it wrong. Ideally you should only store data inside a database, not code.

If you're fetching a PHP structure from the database, consider using a `serialize()`'d version of it (or `json_encode()`'d).

Maybe I have missed the exact purpose of what you're trying to accomplish, do let me know if I'm on the wrong path with my answer.

Whatever you do, don't rely on `eval` unless you really really have to; and even then, don't :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very dangerous, especially if the database content was contributed from a user, but anyway you could use this :

```
eval($your_database_content);
```

[Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 1):

If it is code, you need to use `eval()`, though there are many anti-patterns that involve `eval()`

The manual says:

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.